# How to use ReportingService2010?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm trying to deploy a reporting server solution by code using the reporting server web service: http://_Server_Name_/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl.

Sadly I can't find any examples online. Only some vague information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155071.aspx).

when publishing through the Business Intelligence Development Studio, it publish the shared data source and then publish the reports. I'm trying to so something similar on C#:

```
var service = new ReportingService2010();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

foreach(var dataSourcePath in GetDataSources()) {
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dataSourcePath);
    Byte[] content = GetFileContent(dataSourcePath);
    service.CreateCatalogItem("DataSource", name, parent, true, content, null, out warnings);
}
```

But the CreateCatalogItem gives me the following SoapException exception:

> The input XML does not conform to the
>   schema. XML grammar is described in
>   the API documentation. For XML in
>   reports, refer to Report Definition
>   Language syntax. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidXmlException:
>   The input XML does not conform to the
>   schema. XML grammar is described in
>   the API documentation. For XML in
>   reports, refer to Report Definition
>   Language syntax.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or any other approach I should take?

Comment: I'm having the same problem pushing a DataSource using CreateCatalogItem.

Comment: @Peter Stephens, which reporting server are you using on your development and on your production machine?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. The solution I found is as follows: 
You are using wrong DataSource file format - like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RptDataSource xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="DataSourceXML">
    <ConnectionProperties>
        <Extension>XML</Extension>
        <ConnectString>http://server/_vti_bin/lists.asmx</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
    </ConnectionProperties>
    <DataSourceID></DataSourceID>
</RptDataSource>
```

The right one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSourceDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource">
  <Extension>XML</Extension>
  <ConnectString>http://server/_vti_bin/lists.asmx</ConnectString>
  <CredentialRetrieval>Prompt</CredentialRetrieval>
  <WindowsCredentials>True</WindowsCredentials>
  <Prompt></Prompt>
  <Enabled>True</Enabled>
</DataSourceDefinition>
```

You can get this definition by downloading DataSource from your Reporting Server.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to get the XML for each item out of the report server, in a sense a way to "download" the XML definition for any object including a "DataSource" from the Reporting Server (assuming your report server database is ReportServer):

```
select *, CONVERT(varchar(max),Content) as ContentText
from 
(
      SELECT 
     ItemID,Name,[Type],TypeDescription 
    , CASE 
      WHEN LEFT(Content,3) = 0xEFBBBF 
        THEN CONVERT(varbinary(max),SUBSTRING(Content,4,LEN(Content))) 
      ELSE 
        Content 
      END AS Content 
    from
    (
      SELECT 
         ItemID,Name,[Type] 
       , CASE Type 
          WHEN 2 THEN 'Report' 
          WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Source' 
          WHEN 7 THEN 'Report Part' 
          WHEN 8 THEN 'Shared Dataset' 
          ELSE 'Other' 
         END AS TypeDescription 
       , CONVERT(varbinary(max),Content) AS Content    
       FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog 
       WHERE Type IN (2,5,8)
    ) as ItemContentBinaries
) as ItemContentNoBOM
```

For an SQL data source this is the definition we had:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSourceDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource">
  <Extension>SQL</Extension>
  <ConnectString>Data Source=MyDatabaseServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase</ConnectString>
  <CredentialRetrieval>Integrated</CredentialRetrieval>
  <Enabled>True</Enabled>
</DataSourceDefinition>
```

One thing to keep in mind is that we could not find a way to change the .rds files and get it to work with both the reporting IDE and automatic deployment. We are using a .rptproj with Visual Studio 2008 (Visual Studio 2010 can't work with Sql Server 2008 R2 Reporting Server projects). Visual Studio 2008 requires the DataSource files (*.rds files) to be in the *old schema* format, which won't work with rs.exe and CreateCatalogItem.

If we convert the .rds file to a format that works with CreateCatalogItem, the Sql Server 2008 R2 Reporting Server project gives the following error when trying to open the .rptproj:

> Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer
>   The report definition failed to load: There is an error in XML document (2, 2)..  Verify the report definition conforms to the correct schema. 
>   There is an error in XML document (2, 2). (System.Xml)

```
<DataSourceDefinition xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource'> was not expected. (wp6bqrt3)
```

Answer (score 4):

I've never actually tried adding a DataSource through the Catalog, but I do know a way that works for sure. 
All you need to do is create a datasource that is the same name as the datasource referenced in the report you are publishing.
Here is an example from MSDN using ReportingService2010:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

class Sample
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
    rs.Url = "http://<Server Name>" + 
        "/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx";
    rs.Credentials = 
        System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    string name = "AdventureWorks.rsds";
    string parent = "http://<Server Name>/Docs/Documents/";

    // Define the data source definition.
    DataSourceDefinition definition = new DataSourceDefinition();
    definition.CredentialRetrieval = 
        CredentialRetrievalEnum.Integrated;
    definition.ConnectString = 
        "data source=(local);initial catalog=AdventureWorks";
    definition.Enabled = true;
    definition.EnabledSpecified = true;
    definition.Extension = "SQL";
    definition.ImpersonateUserSpecified = false;
    //Use the default prompt string.
    definition.Prompt = null;
    definition.WindowsCredentials = false;

    try
    {
        rs.CreateDataSource(name, parent, false, 
            definition, null);
    }
    catch (SoapException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code to publish a report and create a datasource, although not written for Reportingservice2010, it shouldn't be to hard to move it over to 2010:

```
Byte[] definition = null;
Warning[] warnings = null;
string parentFolder = "AdventureWorks Sample Reports";
string parentPath = "/" + parentFolder;
string filePath = "D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\Samples\\Reporting Services\\Report Samples\\AdventureWorks Sample Reports\\";
public void Main()
{
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

//Create the parent folder
try {
    rs.CreateFolder(parentFolder, "/", null);
    Console.WriteLine("Parent folder {0} created successfully", parentFolder);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

//Publish the sample reports
PublishReport("EmbeddedDatasource");
}

public void PublishReport(string reportName)
{
try {
    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath + reportName + ".rdl");
    definition = new Byte[stream.Length + 1];
    stream.Read(definition, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
    stream.Close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
try {
    warnings = rs.CreateReport(reportName, parentPath, false, definition, null);
    if ((warnings != null)) {
        Warning warning = default(Warning);
        foreach ( warning in warnings) {
            Console.WriteLine(warning.Message);
        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} published successfully with no warnings", reportName);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
try {
    DataSourceDefinition definition = new DataSourceDefinition();
    definition.CredentialRetrieval = CredentialRetrievalEnum.Store;
    DataSourceReference reference = new DataSourceReference();

    definition.ConnectString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks";
    definition.UserName = "username";
    definition.Password = "password";
    definition.Extension = "SQL";
    definition.WindowsCredentials = true;
    DataSource[] sources = new DataSource[1];
    DataSource s = new DataSource();
    s.Item = definition;
    s.Name = "DataSource1";
    sources(0) = s;
    rs.SetItemDataSources("/AdventureWorks Sample Reports/EmbeddedDatasource", sources);

} catch (Exception exp) {
    Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just discovered that the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createcatalogitem.aspx) for CreateCatalogItem is misleading.

I was trying to deploy a new report in native mode (not Sharepoint) using the webservice, and got an error when I followed the guidance for the Parent parameter:

> Parent
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The fully qualified URL for the parent folder that will contain the item.

The code example on the page shows this:

```
string parent = "http://<Server Name>/Docs/Documents/";
```

So I tried using this format:

```
string parent = "http://<Server Name>/<FolderPath>/";
```

I got the following error:

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidItemPathException: 
The path of the item 'http://<Server Name>/<FolderPath>/' is not valid. 
The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. 
If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash.
```

Then I noticed this in the remarks (contradicting the example which has a slash at the end):

> The Parent parameter cannot be null or empty or contain the following
>   reserved characters: : ? ; @ & = + $ , \ * > < | . ". You can use the
>   forward slash character (/) to separate items in the full path name of
>   the folder, but you cannot use it at the end of the folder name.

After trial and error I was eventually able to deploy the report by setting the parent path to just the folder path, with a forward slash at the start:

```
string parent = "/<FolderPath>";
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH. All the examples I have seen so far just copied and pasted the path from Microsoft documentation without actually explaining how to use the 'parent' path in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to offer some guidance.  I ran through some issues a year ago or so with the ReportingService services and also found little information online, so what I learned from it I posted out here - Hope this helps.

http://www.ericwitkowski.com/2013/05/an-introduction-to-querying-and.html